# Make a Preference (inside a PreferenceFragment) responds to a click

Tags: java, android, xml, preferences

I'm trying to make a preference react to a user-input but with no luck. I'm using PreferenceFragment and seems that not a single code I found so far can help me.

Here is my preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen " >

    <PreferenceCategory
        "
        " >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            "
            "
             o aplicativo para uso"
             aplicativo" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here is my screen code:

```
package com.gh0st.gerenciador;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TelaPreferencias extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public static final String KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN = "prefs_ativar";


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();

    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tela_preferencias, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

I want that, when I touch on the preference, it shows a toast. The code seems to be fine (no errors), but it doesn't work. I think I didn't get the idea behind the listener. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Before I forget, I'm using **API level 19** (Android 4.4). I don't know if this changes something.

Comment: OK... Where do you register (and then hopefully unregister) the listener?

Comment: TBH, I didn't knew I had to register it. The code that you provided worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the registration of the listener? This is how I do that:

```
// Register the listener
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    // Register OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).
    registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Fire the base method
    super.onResume();
}

// Unregister the listener
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // Unregister OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).
    unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Fire  the base method
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Guess I was missing this. Don't remember about reading this on Android Documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make use of the

```
Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener
```

You can find more about it here: **http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html**

Example:

```
Preference p = findPreference("yourkey");
p.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference p) {
            // TODO stuff              
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Edit **concerning deprecation**:

`PreferenceActivity.findPreference("key")` --> [**deprecated**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

`PreferenceFragment.findPreference("key")` --> [**not deprecated**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Isn't that method **deprecated**?

Comment: I was about to say the same. Also, I'll add that I'm using API level 19 (Android 4.4).

Comment: Actually, if used in a PreferenceFragment, findPreference() is not deprecated. Only the old method, of the PreferenceActivity is. The reason why it is shown as deprecated to you is because you are using int in the PreferenceActivity.